# How to do merge operation on multiple cells in csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I am written a python script in which I am creating a .csv file.

To maintain the heading and sub-heading, I want to merges the cells C1 and D1 as given in the image. This image is just a sample image taken from internet.

I am using **csv** package to perform the task. Little snippet of code:

```
import csv
with open('output_summary.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        row_list = ["Section", "Total nb of Points", "Line", "Polygon"]
        writer.writerow(row_list)
```

I want to write **Line** and **Polygon** in two-two cells.

Please suggest me the way with the same package `csv`.

Thanks in advance.

[[image: cell merge]][

Comment: CSV file format doesn't support to mark cells as merged.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher , so, is there any way to write the information in such a way that if we open csv in MS excel, it would look like merged cell?

Comment: Despite what Microsoft pretends, a csv file is not an Excel file but a text Comma Separated Values file.That means that you can only have rows delimited with unescaped end of lines (should be `'\r\n'` whatever the system end of line), containing fields separated with commas (or optionally another delimiter). Fields can contain any character, including separarators or newline provided they are enclosed in quotation marks. But there is no provision at all for formatting.

Comment: You can only try to create a real Excel file. See http://www.python-excel.org/ for external libraries for this task.